# IOS Chrome select box width issue

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, google-chrome

Input type Date and select box not picking its styles on chrome and safari on Iphone 6s Plus/ IOS.

```
.account_form .form .form-control {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3) !important;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

[image: Screeenshot]

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with expected and actual output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to add:

```
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```